# Why is MythTV package in multiverse?

Tags: mythtv, multiverse

> [MythTV](https://www.mythtv.org/) is a Free Open Source software
>   digital video recorder (DVR) project distributed under the terms of
>   the GNU GPL. — MythTV.org

So doesn't that mean it should be listed under Universe?  Why is it listed under Multiverse?:

```
apt-cache policy mythtv
mythtv:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2:0.27.0+fixes.20140324.8ee257c-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
     2:0.27.0+fixes.20140324.8ee257c-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
```

The wiki page on [Repositories](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) says:

- Universe - Community maintained software, i.e. not officially supported software.
- Multiverse - Software that is not free.

Comment: That was asked here too: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mythtv/+question/92963

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the video codecs it ships with. Some of those are NOT open source and are NOT free and for software to be in Universe it needs to be completely free.

---

This on [MythTV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MythTV) will also be a showstopper:

> OpenCable devices are available to access encrypted content on U.S. cable systems, but as this is a full DRM system, and not just CA like DVB CI, every piece of hardware and software on the playback chain must be tested and licensed by CableLabs. At current, Windows Media Center is the only DVR software to meet these requirements, and only it, and other software using its recording libraries, can use these devices. In 2010, CableLabs relaxed the DRM restrictions allowing unlicensed devices to record copy freely content using these devices, however it is still entirely up to cable operators what content they provide flagged as such.

-> never going to end up in "universe"

Comment: Thanks for providing the link and explanation. I understand the first part - if MythTV has codecs that are not free, then the package as a whole would not be free, so goes in multiverse.

Comment: But ignoring the codecs for a bit, I don't understand the second part. How would cable operators determining what content is or isn't copy freely impact whether MythTV software itself is free or not? Aren't the two separate entities? If a video is free, MythTV records it. If is flagged not free, MythTV fails to record it. MythTV itself, as software, could still be free, right?

Or does recording even the copy freely content rely on some non-free code?